# How can I enforce toUpper on a DataField in ASP.Net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm new to WebForms and have no idea how to make this thing work.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode.Code" HeaderText="State" 
            SortExpression="StateCode.Code" />
```

I have a state code, such as CA, that is a text field that can be edited, I know it should be a drop down but that's not my call. Unless there's an easy way to turn this into a drop down box, that would be acceptable.

Anyways, it needs to be forced to upper. I've been trying to set an ItemStyle as below but it's not working. And due to ASP.Net WebForms 'magic', I don't know how to intercept the data before it's saved to the database record to force it to save an uppercase state code.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode.Code" HeaderText="State" 
            SortExpression="StateCode.Code">
<ItemStyle texttransform: "uppercase" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Three things could work.

1. Figuring out why I can't get ItemStyle to work, I've tried every syntax imaginable.
2. Figuring out a way to turn this Bound Datafield into a drop down menu instead.
3. Figuring out how to intercept the data before it's saved to the database.

Here is the datasource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource_School" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=SchoolEntity" DefaultContainerName="SchoolEntity" 
    EntitySetName="School" Where="it.ID = @schoolid" EnableUpdate="True">
 <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" DefaultValue="00" Name="schoolid" />
 </WhereParameters>
```

Comment: What is your data source? How are you retrieving and saving the data?

Comment: It's an EntityDataSource. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: The other two questions are vague and unrelated to this question so IMHO, ask them separately. Please be more verbose too

Comment: Okay. I just wasn't sure what the easiest way to do it. Thank you, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ItemStyle to work, do these

Markup

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode.Code" HeaderText="State" 
            SortExpression="StateCode.Code">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="toUpper" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

CSS

```
.toUpper {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify the `ItemStyle-CssClass` for the `BoundField` as below.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode.Code" HeaderText="State" 
       ItemStyle-CssClass="statuscode" SortExpression="StateCode.Code" />
```

and you css

```
.statuscode {
        text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

If you want to just capitalize the first letter then `text-transform: capitalize;` will work

Comment: And this will ensure that before the text is submitted that it will be uppercase? I've been testing out other methods on top of the ones you and Naveen have mentioned. but no luck yet.